# MobaXTerm - cutting off lines on output larger than window sice - how to change this?

Tags: ssh, putty, mobaxterm, mosh

I am using mobaXTerm as my SSH/Mosh Client ... so far a handy tool. However on MOSH connections, when outputs longer than the screen size arrive, only the most recent lines are shown. If the amount of lines is larger than the screen height, the older lines are cut off at the point where the former output ended.

Therefore you cant inspect text that is longer than the window height. Quite annoying. Couldn't find any settings for this, so far.

Does anyone know how to change this behavior?

Full window size:
[image: Full window size]

Scrolling up a few lines:
[image: Scrolling up a few lines]

Comment: this does not happen on ssh connections

Comment: Did you change/add any settings?

Comment: no, i didn't ..